# Get database name from field?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Currently to reference multiple databases from the same query, we do it like so

```
DatabaseName.Tablename.Column
```

I was wondering if you can actually reference the database name from a field. The reason for this is sometimes there are hundreds of these references and when creating new instances for customers the database names always vary slightly, so these have to be updated.

What I am looking to do is something like this:

```
(SELECT DatabaseName FROM ConfigurationTable).TableName.ColumnName
```

Would this work at all? And if so can you foresee any problems?

Comment: Have you tried? I don't think it'll work, otherwise a lot of dynamic query generation (where you need to dynamically change the table referenced) will use this method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use syntax like in your question.

What you could do is to use dynamic SQL and build the query dynamically based on the database name. For example:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = (SELECT DatabaseName FROM ConfigurationTable)
set @sql = N'SELECT ColumnName FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@sql) + N'..TableName'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have an architecture where each customer has a separate database.

Why are you including the database name in the query?  Just add `use DatabaseName` and run the query as you would want.

Such an architecture normally copies views, stored procedures, functions, tables and whatever else into each database.  If you have a central "code" or "master" database for the application, then the code would often be using dynamic SQL to construct the queries to access the right database.

You cannot dynamically reference a database in a single query.  You would have to use dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Forgot to explain Gordon, each customer uses different databases so the "USE" part makes no difference. It's mostly for the use in views and sprocs

Answer (score 0):

Hardcoding a database name is usually a bad idea. It seems you realized that now.

An alternative would be to create a linked server to the referred database. If the configuration needs to be changed to a different database, you only need to adapt the setup of the linked server without having to change your queries.